# Reset StreamReader for multiple XmlReader.Read() usages

Tags: c#, streamreader, xmlreader

I'd like to re-use a StreamReader I've associated with an XML file for .Read()-Calls from System.Xml.XmlReader.

Basically I've put together a small extension method featuring the following code:

```
 public static string GetValueByPath(this StreamReader str, string attributeName, params string[] nodes)
    {
        str.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(str);
        // Stuff happens here now, not important for the question
    }
```

The StreamReader calling this extension method stays the same throughout the whole Session.

The first time this works just fine, but if I use this method a second time I receive a System.Xml-Exception. Is there no way to effectively "reset" a StreamReader?

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just change the position in the `BaseStream`, because the `StreamReader` is buffering the data from the underlying stream. It will just mess with the behavior of the `StreamReader`, nothing good will come out of it.

You should dispose the old `StreamReader` and create a new one every time instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was afraid this'd be the case. You wouldn't perchance know a way to do this inside an ASP Web Application without unnecessarily bloating up the code?

Comment: @Dennis, not sure what you mean... I can't really answer that without seeing your code

Answer (score 2):

`StreamReader` is not an expensive object to create, so as long as the underlying stream supports setting the position then you should just create a new `StreamReader`on it each time.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's buffering, you need to discard the buffer in addition to resetting the position.

```
            sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
            sr.DiscardBufferedData();
```

I've done this when I want to know how many lines are in the file I'm about to parse (1st pass counts lines, 2nd pass parses and stores results).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this to then end of your method?

```
reader.Close();
```

Your reader might not be closing correctly which is causing issues with the next read.